# Default values when pattern matching a hash in Ruby 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-3

In Ruby 3,

```rb
hash => {a:}
```

works similarly to JS

```js
{ a } = hash
```

except it throws an exception if `:a` isn't a key in `hash` instead of assigning `a = nil`. Ok, we can do

```rb
hash => {a:} rescue nil
```

except this gives undesired result if some keys are present and others missing:

```rb
{a: 1, b: 2} => {b:, c:} rescue nil
puts "b: #{b}, c: #{c}"
```

shows `b` and `c` are both `nil` instead of the desired `b = 2, c = nil`. Is there a simple way to get that result? Or even more generally, emulate JS hash destructuring with non-`nil` default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around missing key error by making an object that responds to `deconstruct_keys`:

```rb
hash = {a: 1}

H(hash) => x:,y:,a:
x  # => nil
y  # => nil
a  # => 1

H(hash, "default") => x:,y:,a:
x  # => "default"
y  # => "default"
a  # => 1

H(hash, x: :z) => x:,y:,a:
x  # => :z
y  # => nil
a  # => 1

H(hash, "default", x: :z) => x:,y:,a:
x  # => :z
y  # => "default"
a  # => 1
```

`deconstruct_keys` is called when hash pattern is used `=> x:,y:,a:`, these keys are passed as argument:

```rb
# DelegateClass to make H be like a hash, but pattern match differently.
# (it works just fine without DelegateClass)
#
#   H.new({a: 1}) # => {:a=>1}
#
class H < DelegateClass(Hash) 
  def initialize(hash, default = nil, **defaults)
    # since hash needs to be duped anyway
    @hash = defaults.merge hash               # defaults for specific key
    @default = default                        # default for any missing keys
    super(@hash)                              # get delegation going
  end

  def deconstruct_keys keys
    missing = keys - @hash.keys               # find what's missing
    missing.each { |k| @hash[k] = @default }  # add it to hash with default value
    @hash                                     # return for pattern matching
  end
end

# H() method, like a Hash() method.
def H(...) 
  H.new(...)
end
```

---

*https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html#label-Matching+non-primitive+objects-3A+deconstruct+and+deconstruct_keys*

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, I've thought of this workaround:

```rb
{a: some_default, **hash} => {a:}
```

or for the second case

```rb
{b: nil, c: nil, **hash} => {b:, c:}
```

I don't love it because it duplicates the keys and does some work to create the left-hand-side hash, and so hope someone has a better option.